# Missing method UnityEngine.VR.VRSettings.get_enabled | Unity IAP purchase not being processed | Android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-play, in-app-purchase

I have an app on the google play store with in-app-purchases.

I'm following the IAP guide on the Unity website... but I am having trouble with the `ProcessPurchase` method not running after `BuyProductID()` is called.

I released an alpha version of my app for testing and made a debug label in my app for feedback.

The relevant parts of my code is shown below:

```
public class PurchasingManager : MonoBehaviour, IStoreListener
{

private static IStoreController m_StoreController;
private static IExtensionProvider m_StoreExtensionProvider;

public Text debugLabel;

public static string product_noAds =        "noads";
public static string product_pts1000 =      "pts1000";

void Start() {...}
void IsInitialized() {...}

public void InitializePurchasing() {
    if (IsInitialized())
        return;

    debugLabel.text = "Initializing...";

    var builder = ConfigurationBuilder.Instance(StandardPurchasingModule.Instance());

    builder.AddProduct(product_noAds, ProductType.NonConsumable);
    builder.AddProduct(product_pts1000, ProductType.Consumable);

    UnityPurchasing.Initialize(this, builder);
}


public void OnInitialized(IStoreController controller, IExtensionProvider extensions) {
    debugLabel.text = "OnInitialized: PASS";
    m_StoreController = controller;
    m_StoreExtensionProvider = extensions;
}

public void OnInitializeFailed(InitializationFailureReason error) {
    dt.text = "OnInitializeFailed InitializationFailureReason:" + error;
}


public void Buy_noads() {
    debugLabel.text = "BUYING noads";
    BuyProductID(product_noAds);
}

public void Buy_pts1000() {
    debugLabel.text = "BUYING 1000";
    BuyProductID(product_pts1000);
}

private void BuyProductID(string productId) {
    if (IsInitialized()) {
        Product product = m_StoreController.products.WithID(productId);
        if (product != null && product.availableToPurchase)
        {
            debugLabel.text = "intializing the purchase";
            m_StoreController.InitiatePurchase(product);
        }
    }
}

public PurchaseProcessingResult ProcessPurchase(PurchaseEventArgs args) 
{

    debugLabel.text = "Processing Purchase now...";

    if (String.Equals(args.purchasedProduct.definition.id, product_noAds, StringComparison.Ordinal)) {
        debugLabel.text = "PURCAHSE noads";
        shop.Purchase(500);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("noads", 1);
    }
    else if (String.Equals(args.purchasedProduct.definition.id, product_pts1000, StringComparison.Ordinal)) {
        shop.Purchase(1000);
        debugLabel.text = "PURCAHSE 1000";
    }
    else {
        debugLabel.text = string.Format("ProcessPurchase: FAIL. Unrecognized product: '{0}'", args.purchasedProduct.definition.id);
    }

    return PurchaseProcessingResult.Complete;

}

public void OnPurchaseFailed(Product product, PurchaseFailureReason failureReason) {
    debugLabel.text = string.Format("OnPurchaseFailed: FAIL. Product: '{0}', PurchaseFailureReason: {1}", product.definition.storeSpecificId, failureReason);
}

}
```

So right after I launch my app the debug label says: "Initializing..." followed by "OnInitialized: PASS".

If i click the button to purchase either of the two products the label says: "intializing the purchase", but it stops there and NOTHING happens.

`ProcessPurchase` is never called since the label doesn't change... Why is it not called? There is no error that i know of, just nothing happens.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

I should add that I followed this YouTube tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3IQ-CvBQz0o&t=73s

EDIT:

Using adb logcat I see that unity prints this error...
[image: MissingMethodException]

What does this mean?

Comment: Have you tried debugging with adb logcat?

Comment: Not sure what that is but i will look into it. Thanks for the suggestion, ill take any help at this point.

Comment: it is a command line tool that comes with android sdk. You can connect your phone to pc and check for errors and warnings. It is quite easy to use it.

Comment: Does the app version have to be a developer build or will logcat also work with alpha version?

Comment: Hi @Dave I eddited my question, unity gives the error shown, How can i fix this?

Comment: Hi, if my answer won't help, try to google the error for other solutions. Logcat should work with any version but you have to enable USB Debugging in your phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to update Unity or the IAP API. Here you can find how to [Remove and Reinstall Unity IAP](https://forum.unity.com/threads/iap-troubleshooting-remove-and-reinstall-unity-iap.511747/). This solution helped smebody with a similiar probem as yours.

Answer (score 0):

Change the location of your Unity installation folder. The new location path should not contain any spaces and should look something like this: C:\Unity\2019.1.5f1\Editor...

instead of : C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.5f1\Editor...

"Program Files" contains space and due to this reason the AssemblyUpdater silently fails.

More details on this particular issue can be found on 
https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/assemblyupdater-silently-fails-if-its-path-contains-spaces